# FileNotFoundException when trying to read xls in android

Tags: android, excel

I'm trying to read excel contents in android, but always get file not found exception
The project is in:

```
C:\AndroidWorkSpace\AntenaProject
```

And the code is:

```
public void TestClick(View view)
{
    File inputWorkbook = new File("shidur.xls");
    Workbook w;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("starting");
    try {

        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
        // Get the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        // Loop over first 10 column and lines

        for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                //CellType type = cell.getType();

                sb.append(cell.getContents());



            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testText);
    tv.setText(sb.toString());


}
```

i tried to put shidur.xls in the following folders:

```
C:\AndroidWorkSpace\AntenaProject\res\raw
C:\AndroidWorkSpace\AntenaProject\res
```

but still getting this exception.
i'm using jxl.jar from http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/
thanks for the help

Comment: put xls in your emulator SDCard. Emulator wont access your hardisk/PC.

Comment: how can i add it and access it ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that you provide to the File constructor needs to be the absolute path of the file, or you need to use the overload that takes another File object as the first parameter which represents the directory the file lives in.

That being said, constructing a file in this way is for files that are either in local storage (ie. phone's main memory) or external storage (ie. SD card).

To open a file from the res/raw directory, get an InputStream in the following way

```
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_name);
```

Then, you will need code that reads the contents of your input stream.  I use a static helper method that looks like this, but this *could* run you into problems if the file is huge.  Hasn't happened to me yet, but in principle that's always a risk when loading the entire content of a file into memory

```
public static String readStream(InputStream in)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
    finally
    {
        // NOTE: you don't have my IOUtils class, 
        // but all these methods do is check for null and catch the exceptions that Closeable.close() can throw
        IOUtils.safeClose(in);
        IOUtils.safeClose(reader);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. thing is it's should read excel row cell by cell
is there an option to do that?

Comment: I just took a look at that JExcelAPI library, and it looks like you can skip the second part of my post about reading the InputStream into a String.  The Workbook class has a getWorkbook method that takes an InputStream as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code to open file in the /res/raw

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shidur.xls)
```

Comment: ok but how can i convert the inputstream to the constructor here:
File inputWorkbook = new File( .... );
because Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook); - inputWorkBook must be File type